# Trying to POST with no body using Retrofit failing with GSON parsing exception

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm integrating with a REST API so I'm using Retrofit. The url I need to hit is:

http://{{server}}/api/v1/stuff/{{id}}/deactivate

I've created an interface that implements the API:

```
@PUT("/api/v1/stuff/{id}/deactivate")
String deactivate(@Path("id") String id);
```

The problem is when I call the method it fails with the following stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046): Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 15  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:67)    
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:393) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        ... 11 more 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 15   
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:779) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769)   
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):  at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:63) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        ... 12 more 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046): Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 15 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:531) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        at com.google.gson.Gson.assertFullConsumption(Gson.java:775) 
E/AndroidRuntime( 3046):        ... 14 more
```

Which I believe is being caused by the fact I'm not posting anything in the body. What is the best way to get around this problem?

Note: I've successfully used POSTMan to call the API.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you write a small sample? Here's what I used: https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/5a0b1608ec728aa21c27

Comment: Thanks for replying @JakeWharton. I figured out on the weekend it was the web service not passing back valid JSON to the client. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned on full debugging using:

```
setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
```

and discovered the Gson parsing error was happening because of incorrectly formatted JSON coming back from the server. I had a "talk" with the server guy to get it fixed.

Sorry for the red herring with the empty body put thoughts. I guess I forgot correlation does not indicate causation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the retrofit. I originally had the following:

```
@POST("/item/{id}")
void postItem(@Path("id") int id, Callback<String> callback);
```

This gave me an exception with okhttp. I changed it to the following:

```
@POST("/item/{id}")
void postItem(@Path("id") int id, @Body String body, Callback<String> callback);
```

and then handled it like this:

```
service.postItem(id, "", callback);
```